# MySQL WITH ROLLUP performance

Tags: mysql, performance

MySQL's WITH ROLLUP clause is a handy feature, but it has its limitations such as inability to combine in with ORDER BY.

Also there are some performance concerns about using it. A well-respected "High Performance MySQL" book suggests that that it may be more appropriate to implement WITH ROLLUP logic in the application instead.

Has anyone done benchmarks about the performance of WITH ROLLUP and/or comparison of having analogue subtotaling logic in application?